# Hiding textbox when it blurs and it's empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a checkbox group with several options, the last one being "other", that it's supposed to show a text input when checked and hide it when unchecked. Also, if you blur from the text input and its empty, it should hide itself and uncheck the option. It mostly works, except that when you uncheck the checkbox and the text field is empty it hides and reappears again, I suppose that it's because several events are triggered, but I cannot find why.

Here's the code

```
$('.last').on('change','input',function(e){
    check=$(this).prop('checked');
    $container_text=$('.other');

    $container_text.toggle(check);
    if (check) {
        $container_text.find('input').focus();
    }


});

$('.other input').on('blur',function(){

    if ($(this).val()=='') {
        $check_pare=$('.last input');
        $check_pare.prop('checked', false);
        $(this).closest('.other').hide();
    }
});
```

the inputs

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="Test 1"/> Test 1</label>
<span class="last">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="Other"/> Other</label>
</span>
<span class="other" ><input type="text" name="Other" value=""/></span>
```

and the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/43ceyd9j/1/

Comment: Try adding `return false;` to the bottom of your `blur` function (but within the `if` statement)

Comment: The reason this is happening is because clicking the checkbox triggers both the blur event on the text input and the change event on the checkbox

Comment: What is the expected behavior here for all events? Why does blur of an input uncheck the checkbox? UI itself is confusing

Comment: @SlashmanX - but even if it triggers both, none of them should be checking the checkbox. In fact it acts like it was receiveng a double click. Seems that if you click "other", then drag the mouse away and release, it works

Comment: @charlietfl - in the real form, selecting at least one option in the checkbox group is mandatory. If you select "other" but don't specify a text, it doesn't count as a valid response, so that's why when you leave (blur) the text field (because you click on send or another input) it unchecks the other checkbox if you left the text field empty.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this in pure CSS but you'd have to build in graceful degradation for IE 8 and below.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="Test 1" id="checkbox-one"/>
<label for="checkbox-one">Test 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="Other" id="checkbox-two" />
<label for="checkbox-two">Other</label>
<span class="other" ><input type="text" name="Other" value=""/></span>
```

**CSS**

```
.other{
    display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label + span {
    display: block;
}
```

By adding the `for` attribute and `id` attribute to your inputs you can use the sibling selector in your CSS.

**Browser Support**

- Chrome: All
- Safari: 3.1+
- Firefox: All
- Opera: 9+
- IE: 9+
- Android: All
- iOS: All

Comment: Problem is that I'm quite limited when it comes to edit the html as it is autogenerated (comes from a wordpress plugin), but I'll take a look

Comment: Which Wordpress plugin are you using? Can you override the standard templates locally in your theme?